# Bedeutung und Grammatik von "wie nebenbei"

Tags: meaning, phrase

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Freunde als sozialpolitische Notwendigkeit also, als Ersatz für die traditionellen Institutionen fürsorglichen Zusammenlebens? Es klingt, als könne das Modell des pensionierten Politikers zumindest einige Probleme der modernen Gesellschaft **wie nebenbei** lösen.

Was bedeutet "wie nebenbei"? [Hier](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/nebenbei) und [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nebenbei) kann ich die Phrase nicht finden. Wie ist diese Verwendung konsequent mit der Tatsache, dass "nebenbei" ein Adverb ist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Wie nebenbei" soll vermutlich "mühelos" bedeuten. Etwas ist so einfach, dass man es *nebenbei* machen kann.

Siehe auch: "Die Zeit vergeht *wie im Flug*." Anstelle eines Adverbs wird ein Vergleich hergestellt.